# How to get getopt.getopt in python

Tags: python

My python script is this:

```
def main(argv):
    print argv
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"h",["help"])
        print opts
        print args
        for opt, arg in opts:
           print opt
```

but when I run it, I see opts is empty.

```
 ./myscript.py debug.lst -s 0 -e 1
['debug.lst', '-s', '0', '-e', '1']
[]
['debug.lst', '-s', '0', '-e', '1']
```

Do you have any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: This can't be your actual code. Please show us code that actually runs and produces your error, instead of vaguely similar code that can't be run at all.

Comment: See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html#getopt.getopt). Your code doesn't match the getopt interface at all.

Comment: @user2357112: His code matches the `getopt` interface perfectly: it's a list of args, a short-options string, and a long-options list. Which is why it's doing exactly the right thing.

Comment: He has the call signature right, but he's expecting getopt to recognize options he hasn't told it to recognize, and he has arguments before options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html#getopt.getopt) clearly say:

> Note Unlike GNU `getopt()`, after a non-option argument, all further arguments are considered also non-options. This is similar to the way non-GNU Unix systems work.

So, this is exactly what you should expect.

If you want GNU-style parsing instead of traditional Unix-style parsing, use `gnu_getopt`.

Or, better, use `argparse` instead of `getopt`. The only good reasons to ever use `getopt` are (a) you know `getopt` like the back of your hand and don't want to learn anything new, or (b) you're porting or maintaining code (possibly from C or another language) that uses `getopt`. Neither of these applies here. The docs say this explicitly, right at the very top of the `getopt` documentation.

---

Also, note that once you fix this problem, one way or another, you're just going to get errors about unrecognized option `-s`.

Answer (score 0):

For gnu_getopt, the following works if you include what options you expect:

```
>>> getopt.gnu_getopt(['myscript.py', 'debug.lst', '-s', '0', '-e', '1'],'hs:e:')
([('-s', '0'), ('-e', '1')], ['myscript.py', 'debug.lst'])
```